# Unknown Failure to Send Email when using Async

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email

I have a website which needs to send an email on a particular action.

```
        var mail = new MailMessage("donotreply@mycompany.com",
                   "myself@mycompany.com", "Generic Subject Title",
                   string.Format("Some body content");

        using (var eServer = new SmtpClient("mailsrv.mycompany.com"))
        {
            eServer.Send(mail);
        }
```

The above code works fine, though the Send function takes between 8-15 seconds to complete, I then receive the email a few seconds later. I would like to remove the delay in page response at the very least.

```
        using (var eServer = new SmtpClient("mailsrv.mycompany.com"))
        {
            eServer.SendMailAsync(mail);
        }
```

When using the above my page loads quickly and finishes all other processes but I never receive the email.

Does anyone have an idea why I wouldn't receive the email simply because I'm using the Async version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the using block, you dispose the 'eServer' variable before it has a chance to actually send the mail. If you use SendMailAsync, you should not directly dispose the SmtpClient afterwards.